# How to display all 3 values in labels while using custombars?

Tags: dygraphs

I am using customBars to render min,avg,max values and everything looks good. On hover, only the avg value is getting displayed in the label. How can I display all the three min,avg and max values in the label.

I already tried using the y valueFormatter, but it gets only the avg value and not all three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, this would normally be done by setting a y-axis [`valueFormatter`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueFormatter), but it's only passed the rounded value, not the confidence interval. This is an API oversight—issue filed [here](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/520).

In the meantime, you can work around the deficiency by determining the row index in an x-axis `valueFormatter` (which is called before the y-axis `valueFormatter`) and using the dygraphs [data API](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#getValue) to access the full tuple of values.

It looks something like this:

```js
axes: {
    x: {
        valueFormatter: function(millis, opts) {
            lastRow = null;
            lastCol = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < g.numRows(); i++) {
                if (g.getValue(i, 0) == millis) {
                    lastRow = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // forward to the default formatter.
            return Dygraph.dateValueFormatter.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    },
    y: {
        valueFormatter: function(num, opts) {
            lastCol++;
            return JSON.stringify(g.getValue(lastRow, lastCol));
        }
    }
}
```

Full working example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s82jj052/3/).

If you're using a rolling average, unfortunately, you'll run into [another issue](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/521): the rolled data is only accessible via a private member variable.

Comment: Works! Thanks for the jsfiddle demo too :)